# Unable to access Django app URL on Heroku after migration to dev database

Tags: python, django, heroku, hosting

I recently migrated my currently running application to the new 'dev' database plan. However, after updating I'm now unable to POST to a specific URL in my Django app. The app still functions the same in my local development environment, so I'm curious if it has something to do with some part of the database migration, such as when I flipped my app into maintenance mode.

The error in the Heroku logs is pretty much a standard 500 error, so it's not very descriptive:

```
POST ... dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=70ms status=500 bytes=5
```

None of the code in the running app has changed - I've only migrated the db using the procedure that Heroku described in their migration guide.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app? Maybe it's still using the old DB credentials. You could also try turning django's debug mode on briefly to catch the exception.

Comment: I did restart the app - no dice. I'll probably try turning on debug mode next to check it out. I think I was hoping that there was just some quirk about maintenance mode that I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that you're app is not pointing at the right database now.

Have you verified that the database is up and running and contains your data?

You can connect to your database and issue queries with:

`heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color> --app your-app`

Secondly, what is the output of `heroku pg:info --app your-app`? Does it indicate that the new, dev database is also `DATABASE_URL`? If not, try

`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color> --app your-app`

And then try again. This sets the database url to the `DATABASE_URL` configuration variable in your dyno, which is presumably what your app uses to connect.

If this doesn't solve it for you, please open a support ticket at help.heroku.com with details such as your app name so that we can investigate.

Comment: Just checked everything - heroku pg:promote tells me that my database is already set to the correct 'color' so I don't think that's it.  I also opened a support ticket (#59063) as well.

Comment: I suggest more generous logging around your app to figure out what's going on - because your database itself is fine.